# TypeError: Cannot read Property 'extend' of undefined , Yeoman Generator

Tags: javascript, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have installed yeoman generator and it is shown in the package.json file , but I get the above error pointing on the Base.^extend in the following line when i run yo my-generator-name

```
module.exports = generators.Base.extend
```

complete file looks so:

```
'use strict';

var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
    method1: function(){
        this.log('Hello World');
    }
})
```

any help would be great!

Comment: Don't forget marking as answered when you get your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that the `extend` method has been deprecated and removed by now. You'll have to use class syntax to extend the generator class.

[v2.0.0](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/releases/tag/v2.0.0)

> ## Breaking changes
>
> Generator.extend() is replaced in favor of `class extends Generator {}`

```
const Generator = require('yeoman-generator');
module.exports = class extends Generator {
   /* your code here*/
}
```